# What does bubble size mean in the context of BubbleChart?

Tags: charts

I am trying to create a graphic with `BubbleChart`, but I have a problem.

- What does size mean in the context of `BubbleChart`? Is it the radius? Is it the area?
- If it is possible, how can I control the sizes of the bubbles for they are not relative to the sizes of bubbles around them?

Comment: Check out the BubbleScale option.

Comment: According to the documentation for [`BubbleScale`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BubbleScale.html), you have three choices for how size is interpreted: diameter, area, and volume. The default is area.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and you know how can I control the sizes of the bubbles for they are not relative to the sizes of bubbles around them?